# Moving VM's in XenServer

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, virtual-machines

When moving a VM from XenServer to an independent box, is it necessary to install XenServer in the new box?

Comment: What do you mean by 'independent box'? And when you say "moving a VM", do you mean something akin to 'live motion/migration' or just the VM file?

Comment: just a migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, yes. Either export the VM and import the resulting file, or join the two machines into a pool and move the VM directly.

However, there are tools around that will convert a virtual to a physical machine. One that gets mentioned frequently on the Citrix website is [PlateSpin](http://www.platespin.com/).

Comment: http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-p2v/ there is tool from redhat which free to use

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that if you join two servers into a pool, when you try to remove one from the pool, all the VM's on that machine are lost!  It basically formats the local storage on that machine.  Moving / Copying VM's is not so easy on Xen 5.5 IMHO. Can't beat the price though!

Comment: I guess moving is quite easy,but the problem is only it takes so much time